# octave-cli does not recognize qt graphics toolkit

Tags: qt, octave

I have compiled Octave 4.2.1 from source with enabled support for Qt (on CentOS 7.4). When I run

```
available_graphics_toolkits()
```

in Octave GUI command window I see

```
ans =
{
  [1,1] = fltk
  [1,2] = gnuplot
  [1,3] = qt
}
```

however if I run same command in `octave-cli` I get different result (`qt` is missing):

```
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = fltk
  [1,2] = gnuplot
}
```

How can I make `octave-cli` see Qt toolkit to use it with `graphics_toolkit("qt")`?

Comment: The `qt` toolkit is only available when running the GUI version of octave (which is `qt` based).

Comment: Thank you @Tasos Papastylianou. So, no way to use `qt` from `octave-cli`. It seems to be a kind of weird restriction.

Comment: I suppose so. Perhaps there's plans to more tightly integrate the qt interface with features only available on the GUI version. Or it's simply to ensure the more lightweight cli version can still be compiled independently of the qt libraries required to build the gui version. At the end of the day it's a design decision; you could ask over at the octave mailing-list / octave irc channel and get an answer from the developers / community itself.

Comment: Of course it's possible to use the Qt toolkit with the CLI version. But you have to open a terminal and execute `octave --no-gui` (btw, On my systems I have an alias"oct" for "octave --no-gui" in .bashrc)

Comment: Thank you @Andy, it does solve my problem. Could you repost it as an answer? Also, what is the reason of having `octave-cli` in addition to `octave --no-gui`?

Comment: @scrutari `octave --no-gui-libs` calls `octave-cli` which is a binary without linking to Qt. `octave --no-gui` doesn't run `octave-cli` but instead octave with Qt libs linked in but without opening the GUI