# octave-cli 8.4.0 does not recognize qt graphics toolkit

Tags: qt, octave

I built octave 8.4.0 for Rocky 8.

Based on the configure output the qt libraries should be linked in and the gui should have been built.

I am trying to run it on a server without X11 but I would still like to be able to produce plots using the qt toolkit.

I have essentially the same issue as:
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47777354/octave-cli-does-not-recognize-qt-graphics-toolkit)
but I'm not running from a terminal emulator inside a window manager.

Should it be possible to use the qt graphics toolkit without X11?

Most of the libraries needed for octave (including qt) are stored in a non-standard location which is a network share.  I therefore need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include all the correct locations.  Is it necessary to set other environment variables so octave can use the qt toolkit?

```
octave:7> available_graphics_toolkits 
ans =
{
  [1,1] = gnuplot
}
```

If I run octave --no-gui, and the search the processes using ps, I see that it is still calling octave-cli.

Based on the post I linked, I was expecting the --no-gui option to start octave and not octave-cli so it could use the qt toolkit

Comment: this would probably be a useful topic to post over at https://octave.discourse.group where the project developers could provide specific advice on your approach

Comment: To anyone who finds this in the future, it does work.  I was missing xcb support in my Qt build.  Once I rebuilt Qt to include the xcb plugin, octave was able to load properly including the qt toolkit.